# Printing square with non repetitive character

Tags: c#

I want to print a rectangle like this :

```
&#*@
#*@&
*@&#
@&#*
```

But problem is that i can't find the algorithm to print this.

I only know how to print a simple rectangle/square

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Out.Write("Saisir la taille : ");
        int taille = int.Parse(Console.In.ReadLine());
        int i; 
        int j;
        for(i = 0; i < taille; i++){
            for(j = 0; j < taille; j++){
              Console.Write("*");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("");
        } 
    }
```

Thank you !

Comment: I think the Mathy term is Permutation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation That might help you with future searches. If you know it is permutations, this might be half the answer you are looking for: https://www.w3resource.com/csharp-exercises/recursion/csharp-recursion-exercise-11.php | It advises using recursion. Wich for such a short array, will have no relevant speed impact over a for. And I do not think there is a non-recursion solution.

Answer (score 2):

First things first unless you need your iterators outside of your loop, just declare them in the for declaration

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Out.Write("Saisir la taille : ");
        int taille = int.Parse(Console.In.ReadLine());
        for(int i = 0; i < taille; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < taille; j++){
              Console.Write("*");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("");
        } 
    }
```

Second you'll need a list of the characters you want to use, given your example

```
char[] chars = { '&', `#`, `*`, '@' };
```

and we'll need a way to know which character we want to use at any given time, say an iterator we can call characterIndex for simplicity. We will increment it each iteration. If incrementing it puts it out of the range of our character array, if characterIndex == 4, we set it back to zero.

```
int characterIndex;
```

To get the scrolling effect you have, before each line we must select a characterIndex that is offset by the row

```
characterIndex = i % chars.Length;
```

Tying it all together

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        char[] chars = { '&', `#`, `*`, '@' };
        int characterIndex;
        Console.Out.Write("Saisir la taille : ");
        int taille = int.Parse(Console.In.ReadLine());
        for(int i = 0; i < taille; i++){
            characterIndex = i % chars.Length;
            for(int j = 0; j < taille; j++){
              Console.Write(chars[characterIndex]);
              characterIndex++;
              if(characterIndex == chars.Length)
                  characterIndex = 0;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("");
        } 
    }
```

Comment: When `taille` == 4 the output will not give the desired scrolling effect.

Comment: Also, when `taille` <= 3, the output scrolls the wrong way. I would consider setting `characterIndex = i % chars.Length` before the second for loop starts.

Answer (score -1):

Getting the permutations by nesting for loops will only work if you know exactly how many elements there will be. Basically you need to write a for-loop for every element after the 1st.

The proper way to deal with this is Recursion. While there are cases where Recursion and nested for-loops are interchangeable. And in cases where they are, for loops have a potential speed advantage. While normally the [speed rant](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) applies to such differences, with the sheer amount of data both Recursion and Loops might have to deal with, it often maters - so best to prefer loops where possible.

Permutations is AFAIK not a case where loops and recursion are interchangeable. Recurions seems to be mandatory. [Some problem as simply inherently recursive](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HXNhEYqFo0o). As the [recursion version](https://www.w3resource.com/csharp-exercises/recursion/csharp-recursion-exercise-11.php) is fairly well known, I will not post any example code.

You should defiitely use Recursion. With your example code I basically asume you are:

- In a learning environment
- You just learned recursion
- A input variant recurions can effortless solve (like a 6 or 20 size input), is the next assignment